# Entity Framework - Explicit loading objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently having an issue with explicit loading in Entity Framework.
I've disabled Proxy Creation and Lazy Loading in my datacontext.

```
 public DataContext()
     : base("")
 {
     Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
     Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
 }
```

This has been done because I need to be able to serialize my entity framework objects, which I cannot do when using virtual properties because this creates a virtual property.

I would like to retrieve the entity 'ContentType':

```
[Table("T_CONTENT_TYPES")]
public class ContentType : Entity
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the content type.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the <see cref="Folder"/> in which this item belongs.
    ///     If this field is empty, it means that this item is stored in no particular folder, which means it's stored in the root.
    /// </summary>
    [Column(Order = 100)]
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is done by using this code:

```
var contentType = UnitOfWork.ContentTypeRepository.GetById(Id);
```

As you see, my entity has a reference to a Folder. Since LazyLoading & Proxy Creation is disabled, I use the following code to retrieve the folder:

```
((DataContext) UnitOfWork.DataContext).Entry(contentType).Reference(x => x.Folder).Load();
```

My complete method is then:

```
 public ContentType GetById(int Id)
 {
     var contentType = UnitOfWork.ContentTypeRepository.GetById(Id);

     ((DataContext) UnitOfWork.DataContext).Entry(contentType).Reference(x => x.Folder).Load();

     return contentType;
 }
```

The GetById method looks like the following:

```
public TEntity GetById(int id)
{
    if (GetEntityById != null)
    { GetEntityById(this, new EventArgs()); }

    var returnData = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if (GetEntityByIdFound != null)
    { GetEntityByIdFound(this, new EventArgs()); }

    return returnData;
}
```

However, the 'Folder' property is still null.
Anyone has an idea why this is not working?

If somebody knows a good working alternative for serializing lazy loaded entities, I'm prepared to integrate that one.

Comment: Is the folder actually null/empty in the datastore?

Comment: Geez, how could I have overlooked that stupid simple thing. It was indeed empty.

Comment: easy fix. Glad it worked for you